# When did Aquaman lose his left hand?

Tags: dc, episode-identification, dc-animated-universe, character-development, aquaman

Aquaman is definitely *not* the same superhero I grew up watching and reading about. He seems to have undergone a change from his mild mannered full bodied self to a somewhat darker and more disturbed long-haired character with a prosthetic left hand. Aquaman Wiki says some bad guy named [Charybdis](http://aquaman.wikia.com/wiki/Charybdis) fed Aquaman's hand to piranha. Which comic book or animated TV episode or Movie first told the tale?

[image: New Aquaman]

*Not the mild mannered Aquaman I remember.*

Comment: Aquaman made the mistake of thinking a swimming Vietnamese Pot-bellied Pig was an aquatic animal. This also explains why he flies into a rage every time reruns of Green Acres is on basic cable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It happened in Aquaman (1994 series) #2, cover date September 94.

[image]

Aquaman loses his hand when Charybdis steals his ability to communicate with sea life and sticks Arthur's hand into a piranha-infested pool which results in the loss.

Comment: Could someone edit this and explain what we're seeing? It looks like Aquaman's hand is being eaten away by *water*.

Comment: Added context. Tho to be fair the detail is in the q anyway.

Comment: But that detail was speculation from an unlinked Aquaman wiki. The image didn't seem to support it because there are no piranha visible, so I appreciate you adding the context.

Answer (score 20):

In 2001, it was displayed in the *Justice League* animated TV episode *The Enemy Below* (Season 1 Episode 3). He cut off his hand so he could get free in time to save his only son, the prince of Atlantis, from being murdered by his brother Orm.

[image: Aquaman prepares to sever his hand to escape]

Comment: Worth noting: Aquaman himself was about to die, along with his son.  He cut off his own hand deliberately, while chained to a giant boulder next to a baby falling face-first into an undersea volcano.  Because awesome.